# Auth. Providers and Named Credentilas for Salesforce Security Review

Tags: security-review

We have managed package, where in we are asking users to configure Auth. Providers,Named Credentials after package installation as user might need to change endpoint when user have to connect to different environment.

We are using named credentials and authenticating API callout using Oauth 2 principle.

External system provides `Consumer Key` and `Consumer Secret`, which user will enter inside Auth. Provider after package installation.

As user with `View Setup and Configuration` , `Customize Application`
AND `Manage Auth. Providers` can view and Edit.

Is this allowed when it comes to managed package and getting passed from Sales-force Security review , please suggest and advise.